# Migrating Visual Studio Solution from x86 to x64 Developer Environment

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, migration, 32bit-64bit

I've looked around and tried many suggestions but none have worked. I recently migrated a web-based application I developed in Visual Web Developer Express 2010 on a 32-bit machine to a newer 64-bit machine. After re-configuring everything the way I had it, I'm trying to re-compile my code but I keep getting this stupid error which makes no sense to me:

```
Error 4: Task could not find "AxImp.exe" using the SdkToolsPath
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" or the
registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A".
Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is
installed.
```

Also when I view the Project Properties the References, Resources, and Settings tabs all display the following error. I can't for the life of me figure out what to do. All I want to do it compile the bloody project.

```
Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'.
This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework
moniker is incorrectly formatted.
```

What in tarnation is that supposed to mean? Does this have anything to do with the CLR? I'm just taking shots in the dark at this point. Help would be sorely appreciated :)

**UPDATE - Still Not Working**

I'm certain it's **not my .NET 4** installation **because my application is working** just fine, I just can't compile my dev version. **Nothing has changed since the last computer other than the CPU architecture**. I've also uninstalled & re-installed Visual Web Developer thrice since this post and get the same error message each time when trying to view the tabs I listed above.

I used the "[Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4321)" and "Unattended Uninstall" commands from the [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/12/10011664.aspx) for both Client and Full (i.e. Extended) Profiles each time to do a **complete clean install**. Nothing...

Since I was able to view these tabs on the HelloWorld test app I created, that indicates to me that my solution did not "convert" (what-have-you) properly to the x64 architecture. I could create a new solution and it would probably work but this would be very time consuming. **There must be a way to edit the properties file (if I only knew which is was) to fix the path, string, or whatever is causing those tabs not to properly display and my solution not to compile.** Thanks ;)

Comment: You obviously *didn't* configure everything the way that you had it. It looks like something went badly wrong in your installation of Visual Studio. Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET Framework?  All of those messages point to a corrupted installation of .NET 4.0. or Visual Studio.  Or perhaps you don't even have 4.0 installed.

Comment: Have you checked that the .NET 4.0 framework is installed on your new machine?  If you don't want to target 4.0, you can try changing the target framework (under Project Properties) to what you want to use.

Comment: @All I'm not a complete noob, lol. Of course I installed .NET 4.0. I even tried doing a repair. I was trying not to re-install because I didn't want to take the server down, but I guess I have no choice. I'll get back to you guys. Thanks for the tips :) Oh, also note that I compiled a HelloWorld app as a test just fine. Of course this doesn't use any .NET 4 stuff so I'm not sure if the test was adequate.

Comment: Hmm, this is why you shouldn't perform updates on production servers.

Comment: AxImp.exe is used for importing ActiveEx controls and creating the .net wrapper for them.  The issue may only affect projects that have references to old COM controls.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ccdh774(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @Cody, Well I know that... I haven't exactly been given me a lot to work with. My production server = my development box fcol >.<  Fortunately the website is not in heavy use yet, so it won't kill us to have it down a bit for maintenance.

Comment: @DavidStratton What I don't understand is why it's even asking for AxImp.exe. I've never made use of the utility and I certainly have not implemented it in my code. I think if I can fix the "cannot resolve mscorlib" error, then the other might go away? It seems it's not mapping to the proper framework or folder? Not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix my first issue I had to copy the "AxImp.exe" file from another place on my drive to the path where VS was looking for it. This file is part of the [Windows SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) which can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279). You can also remap VS to use the new version & architecture as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660764.aspx).

To (really) solve my second issue I had to re-create my Solution from scratch by making a fresh new one and re-adding all my code and references. I think something happened in the update that corrupted my solution properties file (*.vbproj) or something.

Lastly, I'd highly recommend installing the 64-bit version of SQL server on a 64-bit machine to avoid [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) errors like I got. You may not, but better safe than sorry >.< I installed the "SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe" version from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26729).

There's also a somewhat insightful article MSDN article called "[Migrating 32-bit Managed Code to 64-bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx)" (2005, pretty old).

I hope this helps whoever may stumble across this question and is having the same issues :)

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this problem only when i added Microsoft.Office.Core to References from COM.
Then instead of selecting from COM, i did browse and selected one from C:\Windows\Assembly\GAC location, which solved this problem, there was no other issue to cause this AxImp.exe missing issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

adding ms office word and excel interop  files from GAC solved my problem.